# JSON - Search for Value of String in Json with JS

Tags: php, javascript, json, cookies

I need a simple way to search my Json string, using javascript.

Here's my PHP that creates my Json String:

```
<?php
$allnames = array();
$res = mysql_query("SELECT first,last FROM `tbl_names`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  $allnames[$i++] = $row['first'].':'.$row['last'];
}

echo $jsonstring = json_encode($allnames);
/* 
["john:smith","tony:stark","bruce:banner","clark:kent"]
*/
?>
```

I intend to put that `$jsonstring` into a cookie, so I can reference it on several different pages, saving me from making any future queries.
I'm using the jquery cookie plugin from: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.cookie("allNames", JSON.stringify(<?=$jsonstring;?>))
});
</script>
```

So far so good!  The cookie exists, and the data is saved, I can see in the browser.

I'm now interesting in searching that cookie's value, for instances of any of those names.
And if I find one, I'll have options to perform, depending on my pages.

What I'd like to do is perform an onkeyup event, from a text box on a page:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#lastname").keyup(function() {
    // search the "allNames" cookie value for lastname
     var allNames = $.cookie("allNames"); // gets cookie
     var lastname = $(this).val();

     // this is not seeming to work:
     if( allNames.text().search('stark') != -1){
        alert("that name exists");
     }else{
    alert("name does not exist");   
     }

  });

});
</script>
```

I'm sure it's an easy task that I'm just not grasping. And maybe json isn't the best way to save cookie data either.

But how would I search a cookie's value?
Or can someone advise a better solution?

Comment: You know you can set cookies with PHP rather easily?

Comment: I don't think storing all these values in a cookie is a good idea. Cookies are sent to the server with every request, increasing the size of every request (even for images, CSS,...)

Comment: All cookies on the domain are sent to the server, on every page request?  (referenced or not?)

Comment: @coffeemonitor: Only the cookies matching the domain. Use Fiddler and analyze HTTP traffic to understand how cookies work.

Comment: The `indexOf` search could give you false positives, like saying that there's already a 'Jon' when there's only a 'Jonathan'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

First create the JSON and store in cookie:

```
<?php
    $allnames = array();
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT first,last FROM `tbl_names`");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $allnames[$row['last']] = $row['first'];
    }

    setcookie("allNames", json_encode($allnames), time()+(3600*24*10)); //10 days
?>
```

Then get it :

```
$(function(){
    $("#lastname").on('keyup', function() {
        var allNames = JSON.parse($.cookie("allNames")); // gets cookie
        var lastname = this.value.trim();

        if (lastname in allNames) {
            alert("that name exists");
        }else{
            alert("name does not exist");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `lastName in allNames`  is not going to work, you keyed allNames by first name not by last. `"stark" in {john:"stark"} => false` `"john" in {john:"stark"}`

Comment: Now it works, I'm just not upvoting yet because the OP intended for a search on both first and last names, I think? The example shows a last name but the text of the question seems to indicate it could be either

Comment: switched them around, as it was easiest, otherwise one could just use a little $.grep to check for values. It's no problem to search for both first an last name, but I'm guessing an element with the ID #lastname is for a last name, and if the OP wanted something for a firstname as well, he'd mention it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `if( allNames.text().search('stark') != -1){`  is wrong, `allNames` doesn't have a `text()`  method, you should be getting an error on your console saying that "Object  has no method 'text'"

It should just be

```
if( allNames.search('stark') != -1){
```

However, this has the problem of giving you false positives: say there's a first name that's the same as a last name or if there is a last name that is a substring of another.

If you are just searching on last names, you should improve your structure as adeneo suggested, a map keyed by last name, or you'll need to be more careful than just using an `indexOf`, like the following

```
 var lastNames = JSON.decode(allNames).map(function(name){
     return name.split(":")[1];
 });

 // Note that this is not String.indexOf, it's Array.indexOf so it doesn't
 // suffer from the false positives from matching substrings
 if (lastNames.indexOf(lastName) > -1) {
      // Found it
 }
```

Comment: You're right about the false positives.  It's actually the reason I'm combining the first and last names with the colons.  It's not perfect, but it's meant to keep some sense of unique searching.  I'm still open to better ways

Comment: @coffeemonitor What's wrong with what I suggested? That fixes your problem, it extracts the last names and it doesn't have the false positives.

Answer (score 0):

For the cookies part, if you are using HTML5 I suggest you use local storage API http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp since you don't want to send a huge amount of data in the cookies all the time.